# You are using an unsupported command-line flag: --ignore-certifcate-errors. Stability and security will suffer

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I know that this is a duplicate question **BUT**.. I've also search Google and tried the recommendation and my code still has the bug. `StackOverflow` is my last resort, kindly help me investigate this issue. Thanks a lot!

So.. I'm already using the latest version of chrome driver that was available on the website (`2.29`) but I'm still getting the notification when I launch my small `js` file, resulting to not being able to go to the specific URL.

Below is my `js` code:

```
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');

var driver = new webdriver.Builder().withCapabilities(webdriver.Capabilities.chrome()).build();

driver.get('https://www.google.com');
```

This `ERROR` also shows up in my `nodejs cmd` after the browser is launched:

```
C:\Users\Jon\Desktop>node stockinfo.js --compiled the jsfile
C:\Users\Jon\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2634 --ERROR starts here
        throw error;
        ^

Error: ECONNREFUSED connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:63925
    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Jon\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\http\index.js:238:15)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at Socket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:309:9)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at emitErrorNT (net.js:1281:8)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:80:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9)
From: Task: WebDriver.navigate().to(https://www.google.com)
    at thenableWebDriverProxy.schedule (C:\Users\Jon\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver.js:816:17)
    at Navigation.to (C:\Users\Jon\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver.js:1140:25)
    at thenableWebDriverProxy.get (C:\Users\Jon\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver.js:997:28)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Jon\Desktop\stockinfo.js:5:8)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
```

Comment: Please check your editor and check whether the driver is compatible with the editor version. Sometimes compatibility can be the problem for the issue. Use driver version 2.28 instead.

Comment: @kripindas I've solved my own problem. Kindly check below. Thanks though! :)

Comment: @JpaulPunzalan..Glad to hear it. Finding solution for the problem by ourself is always appreciable. Happy coding. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix my problem.

I included `C:\Users\Jon\node_modules\chromedriver\lib\chromedriver` as **Path** on `Environment Variables`. You could access it by following these steps:

```
Control Panel > System > Change Settings > Advanced Tab > Environment Variables > 
System Variable table > Path Variable row > New > Copy paste the location I posted above 
> click OK to close all windows
```

I also used the **conventional**  `script`. Please see below:

```
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver'),
    By = webdriver.By,
    until = webdriver.until;

var driver = new webdriver.Builder()
    .forBrowser('chrome')
    .build();

driver.get('http://www.google.com/');
```

**PS** Do not install `selenium-webdriver` and `chromedriver` **npm** packages **globally!**